# Why Settings App is taking so much space?

Tags: 8.1, nokia-lumia-620

I was checking the used space on my Lumia 620 with the storage check App from settings (*not* the [storage sense](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/storage-on-my-phone) App) and I found something odd. The settings App is taking a lot of space!

[image]

Is this normal behavior? Or is it an error of the storage check App? If not, there is some way to free that used space?

I also noticed that most of my installed Apps arent' showed in the list.

Comment: I guess its a normal behaviour, because i am using the same phone and have same stats and I am not facing any problem.

Comment: I'm not facing any problem too, but I was wondering if something was wrong about all that used space.

Comment: I don't think there is something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As Nisha pointed out this seems to be normal. In fact, my settings seem to have 4,4GB (Lumia 930). It's weird though, the app also only shows a few of the installed apps. Not sure what criteria they match...

Comment: With storage sense App I'm getting completely different values about space used by Apps, System etc.
I think in the future WP should only include one App between storage check and storage sense, in order to minimize confusion and clutter.

Comment: Yeah, I'm with you on that one. I suspect the settings size to include all missing apps.

Comment: The difference is that Storage Sense is by Microsoft and Storage Check is by Nokia. Storage Sense is generally more accurate.

Comment: Mine is taking 6.33MB on a Lumia 930 (stable version)... (Storage Sense)